# Android: steps to upload a file to server over http

Tags: java, android, server

Im since a week trying to upload a file over http to a server. I have found hunderts of tutorials but I cant work with them. Some classes and methods are depricated and so on. Now I want to do it by my own but I need to know the steps.

Right know I have an image on my phone that I want to upload. What are the steps I need to do?

- Convert Image to Bitmap

Comment: to send a file you have to use Multipart request

Comment: Look `okhtttp`: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file

Comment: You can use Multipart or Multipart with the Retrofit library which is used for Network calls..

Answer (score 1):

Upload your image as binary(byte array)

here is code you can reffer :

```
String url = "http://yourserver";
File file = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
    "Your_file");
try
{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
     InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
     new FileInputStream(file), -1);
     reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
     reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
     httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     //Do something with response...

}
catch (Exception e)
{
     // show error
}
```